# do I need to include any SQL .dll for VB.net app

Tags: sql, vb.net, dll

App accesses MS SQL database hosted on IIS server.

Only import is :

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

App is standalone executable.

Do I need to include any additional `.dll` files with the build?

Seems to work fine on just about every computer I use from Win XP and up.  Just want to make sure.

Comment: If it works then you have all dependencies (by definition) as long as you are not late loading any assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

1. System.Data.SqlClient is a part of .NET framework, so if the machine has the correct version of .NET installed - you should be good to go.
2. You can ensure that you have .NET by making an installer which checks for it (also good for mundane things like updates, uninstalls, creating shortcuts and so on)